# Preg for checking how many time it occurs

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Here I am having one preg

```
[-0-9a-zA-Z \/_:.,;=\'{0,2}"{0,2}\s]+$
```

With this I want to check lines whether they contains Alphabets, Numeric and some special character such as `- _ , . ; ' " / =`. I am getting everything proper but here the issue I faced is with `'` & `"`. Here I want to use this like if quotes are open then it should be closed as well or incase it should not be in use. Either 0 or only 2 times it can be used not more than that.

Example

`"hello; max` This should not be allowed

`"hello; max"` This could be allowed if there is no any quotes then also it should allow.

`'hello; max'` This should be allowed

`hello; max` This should be allowed

Comment: Are we talking about quotes at the start and end only, or do you also want a match if the quoted part was in the middle? `Foo"bar"baz`, is that a match, or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(["']?)[-0-9a-zA-Z\/_:.,;= ]+\1$
```

In PHP:

```php
preg_match('~^(["\']?)[-0-9a-zA-Z/_:.,;= ]+\1$~', $text)
```

Or, since `[A-Za-z0-9_]` = `\w`,

```php
preg_match('~^(["\']?)[-\w/:.,;= ]+\1$~', $text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lWcFme/3).

Replace the literal space with `\s` if you need to handle any whitespace.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(["']?)` - Group 1: an optional `'` or `"`
- `[-0-9a-zA-Z\/_:.,;= ]+` - one or more ASCII letters, digits, `/`, `:`, `.`, `,`, `;`, `=` or space
- `\1` - match and consume the same char as in Group 1 at the current location
- `$` - end of string.